# Assigning licenses to a guest user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365

I have purchased an office 365 E3 subscription and want to assign the licenses to my guest users. What is the recommended way to proceed?

Comment: Thanks a lot @MdFaridUddinKiron. It seemed to work. How does the user to whom the licenses were assigned make use of them? Does the user login normally and, for example, download the office application?

Comment: Do you have any more concern?

Comment: Thanks Farid. I tried with a dummy account and tried to login to login.microsoftonline.com. It told me that the account does not exist. Fair enough. Then I tried with the email address assigned to the guest user on onmicrosoft.com. It seem to recognise the user but then asked me for the password and I cannot reset the password. Is this the right process or am I not doing something right?

Comment: Yeah you are doing wrong.. For resetting password you should have `user administrator` or `password administrator` role. Or guest user in his home tenant can reset then can try what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks. I am still a bit confused on how the guest user can access the office 365 apps. Any additional information on that will be immensely helpful.

Comment: You could refer [this docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/admin/create-groups/manage-guest-access-in-groups?view=o365-worldwide)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** You cannot assign licence to guest user directly. It is not supported.

**Work Around:**

To assign Office 365 license to `Guest User` you could follow below steps.

***1. Create a group on azure active directory***

***2. Add your `guest user` to that group***

[image]

***3. Now assign licence to that group***

[image]

***After assignment:***

[image]

***Check User License:***

Now go to the `Guest User` profile and click on `Licenses` you should see your assignment right there. See the screen shot

[image]

Comment: I thought users need to have P1 in order to use group-based licensing. How does that work?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-licensing-whatis-azure-portal