# How do I buy an Office licence within Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365, virtual-machine

I have set up a very basic Azure Virtual Desktop scenario for testing, using a [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-desktop/tutorial-create-connect-personal-desktop). That all went fine, so I have a user in Azure Active Directory who can connect via Remote Desktop to a Windows 11 VM.

I would like this user to be able to use Office, which is already installed because I chose the base VM image which includes it.

It looks like in Azure it's straightforward to assign Office licenses to users, there are Microsoft docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/licensing-groups-assign) and some screenshots in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57233189/1688738). However I cannot work out: in the first place **with which API can I purchase Office licenses so they appear in the Azure portal available to assign to users**?

I've spent hours reading Microsoft documentation but I keep finding myself landing in documentation that is not Azure-specific, but instead a parallel world of Microsoft 365 with its own separate admin control panel, administrator login and payment account.

I found some [instructions](https://github.com/uglide/azure-content/blob/master/articles/billing-add-office-365-tenant-to-azure-subscription.md) which look promising but it seems outdated. The management portals look completely different nowadays and I can't understand the terminology, maybe because Microsoft has rebranded everything again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this

https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home?#/licenses

https://admin.microsoft.com/AdminPortal/Home?#/catalog

Pretty sure the Azure AD service just redirect you there for purchasing and also for assigning licenses.

If you are specifically asking for the API to purchase licenses from Microsoft. Currently you can not buy license through Microsoft's API as far as I know. You can use the Graph API to assign existing licenses though
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer

[image]

Comment: Thank you. I can see and buy more licenses in the 'Microsoft 365 admin center'. My issue is, how do I manipulate those licenses from the Azure side?

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can buy in M365 admin center and assign those license in Azure AD
Which other "manipulation" do you need?

Comment: M365 admin centre isn't scriptable and integrated with Azure, so I can't use all the good IaC/API stuff, for example automatically purchasing a new Microsoft 365 subscription when a new user signs up.

Comment: As far as I know, purchasing in M365 admin (Purchasing directly through Microsoft) is not scriptable / available through API. I heard that there are non-Microsoft provider that provide API to buy license (and assign those bought license to your M365 account)