# Not Able to Send Email on behalf of user using Microsoft Graph API ( Tenant GUID Not Found Error)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

We are creating an app to provide email services. The user can schedule the email sending as well.

For proof of concept using Microsoft Graph API on Java we created an app on Microsoft Azure, set up the permissions on App and added the users. I am writing JAVA POC for this using msalj and Microsoft Graph API.

```
IAuthenticationProvider iAuthProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(clientSecretCredential());
        
GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                .<Request>builder()
                .authenticationProvider(iAuthProvider)
                .buildClient();

//Creating msg body for Email
Message message = new Message();
graphClient.users(senderUserEmail).sendMail(UserSendMailParameterSet
        .newBuilder()
        .withMessage(message)
        .withSaveToSentItems(saveToSentItems)
        .build()).buildRequest()
    .post();
```

I am using clientCredentialAuth for getting token. I do have all the values ClientID, ClientSecret, TenantId. Method clientSecretCredential() is defined as below.

```
    private ClientSecretCredential clientSecretCredential() {

        return new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
          .clientId(clientId)
          .tenantId(tenantId)
          .clientSecret(clientSecret)
          .build();
        }
```

I get the error

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound",
    "message": "The tenant for tenant guid {tenantId} does not exist.",
    "innerError": {
      "errorUrl": "https://aka.ms/autherrors#error-InvalidTenant",
      "date": "2024-02-04T11:18:24"
    }
  }
}
```

Update: So what @Rukmini is suggesting that is what we are doing but at Java side. It seems it is not working because we don't have license of Office 365. I am working on getting it to try again.

Comment: Well, did you check the tenant id? How did you determine the tenant id?

Comment: What do you mean by checking tenant Id ? I input the same tenant Id that i got from portal.azure.com under App

Comment: Well, either you copied the wrong id or `tenantId` is not set correctly. If you debug, is the value of `tenantId` set to the correct value?

Comment: Yes, It is set to correct value. Could it be due that account I have is Free Trial account ?

Comment: The error usually occurs if the license is missing in your tenant to perform the action. To resolve the error, subscribe O365 license and assign O365 license to the users

Comment: @Rukmini shouldn't it work with Free tier account ? Paid subscription is must ?

Comment: You mean O365 license free trail?

Comment: Yes O365 Free trial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To send mail on behalf of the user, check the below:**

Create a Microsoft Entra ID application and grant API permissions:

[image]

I generated **access token via Client Credential flow** via Postman:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/TenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:ClientID
client_secret:ClientSecret
grant_type:client_credentials
scope:https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

[image]

Using the above access token, I am able to send the mail successfully:

```json
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/UserID/sendMail
Content-type: application/json

{
  "message": {
    "subject": "Meet for lunch?",
    "body": {
      "contentType": "Text",
      "content": "The new cafeteria is open."
    },
    "toRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "frannis@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "ccRecipients": [
      {
        "emailAddress": {
          "address": "danas@contoso.onmicrosoft.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "saveToSentItems": "false"
}
```

[image]

The error ***"OrganizationFromTenantGuidNotFound"*** usually occurs if the user doesn't have assigned Office 365 license. Make sure to subscribe Office 365 license to the tenant.

[image]

**If still the issue persists**, then check the below:

- Verify the **`TenantID`** you are passing is valid.
- If you are making use of **personal** Outlook account to send mail then you have to make use of interactive flows to send mail. Refer this [**SO Thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657118/the-tenant-for-tenant-guid-x-does-not-exist-for-self-email-accountim-the-on) by Sridevi.
- Make sure to pass **scope** as `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

Comment: I do have same permission as you only thing that is different is I have free tier account and No Paid License of O365. Should it work with Free tier.

Comment: Is the license assigned to the user?

Comment: And the user is Azure AD user that is work account or personal account?

Comment: We do not have any license. It's free tier account of microsoft azure. user is Azure AD.

Comment: You should have office 356 licence and assign it to the user to resolve the error

Comment: You can send mail in Microsoft Azure free trail but office 365 license is required

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75680843/how-do-i-buy-an-office-licence-within-azure

Comment: I Conclude that we are not able to send the email because we don't have Office 365 license. We are working on getting office365 license. I will mark this ticket as closed.